# Javascript - Loop and Compare Array Values by Using Associated Key

Tags: javascript, loops, object, compare, associative-array

Searched and tried with no luck, I guess it's time to ask ;-)

A **JSON array** is sent with **Objects as items**, inside each object, there are **values associated with keys**, i.e.

```
[{"name":"Jack", "message":"Hello!"},
 {"name":"John", "message":"Hi!"},
 {"name":"Jack", "message":"Hello Again!"}]
```

I am using

```
$.each(json, function(){//--Do a Listing--//});
```

which renders a list like:

```
<ul>
    <li><span>Jack:</span>Hello!</li>
    <li><span>John:</span>Hi!</li>
    <li><span>Jack:</span>Hello Again!</li>
</ul>
```

as looping all items out. However, if you have noticed that inside the JSON package, there will be duplicated keys - 'name' which I would like, instead of making a separated listing item, to make them stack together, e.g. to display as 'Jack +1' which is something like:

```
<ul>
    <li><span>Jack: (+1)</span>Hello!</li>
    <li><span>John:</span>Hi!</li>
</ul>
```

So far, the looping is not a problem. The problem is how to compare the value with the same key while looping them out and then do something with them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And what will happen with the second message from Jack?

Comment: the <li> actually comes with a onClick() which provides a detailed page for that conversation.

Comment: Ok, so you actually dont need all the messages at the same time, so maybe you data structure is not right, like @Vladimir says in his answer

Comment: the original JSON pack structure is fixed on the server-side, generated by PHP and it is out of my hands, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to build another one object according to the one you have, but in more convinient form. Like this one:

```
{
   "Jack": {
      "message": "Hello!",
      "times": 2
   },
   "John": {
      "message": "Hey",
      "times": 1
   }
}
```

So your programm will have two loops. First one which simplifies initial array, and second one loop renders html.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I am correct, what you have meant is for me to change the structure of the JSON package. That is something I could not. Otherwise, if I follow you correctly, I need to loop out the original JSON package, then restructure it into what you have suggested, then use 2 loops to do the final render. Am I right?

Comment: One loop to restructure and another one to render. Take a look at @daver answer, it will give you basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
var data = [{"name":"Jack", "message":"Hello!"},
   {"name":"John", "message":"Hi!"},
   {"name":"Jack", "message":"Hello Again!"}];
var messages = [];

for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
   if(!messages[data[i].name]){
      messages[data[i].name] = 0;
   }
   messages[data[i].name] += 1;
}

console.log(messages);

/*Output
   [Jack: 2, John: 1]
*/
```

In the case that you dont need the messages at the same time